# How to setup a project to route with React, Redux and TypeScript using Provider, Router and Route?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am working on a project using TypeScript, React and Redux. Currently I came across the issue that I want to route a user that is not authenticated directly to a login page, otherwise to the content page.

My main problem is that I receive a TypeScript compile error, because I cannot figure out the right type definitions for the Route components. I checked on several tutorials online, whereas I cannot manage to port their code and get it working with my example.

Here is my index.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Reducers, InitialState } from './reducers';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import App from './app/App';
import Content from './components/pages/Content';
import Login from './components/pages/Login';
import Overview from './components/containers/Overview';
import Payment from './components/containers/Payment';
import Profile from './components/containers/Profile';

const history = createHistory();    
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...Reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  InitialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(middleware)),
);

function isAuth() {
  let user = FirebaseApp.auth().currentUser;
  return user !== null;
}

const app = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={Content}>
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Overview} />
          <Route path="/payment" component={Payment} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Route>
        <Route onEnter={isAuth}>
          <Route component={Login} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  app
);
```

The IDE is showing errors at the following lines: [IDE shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA21y.png)
and the compiler throws the following error:
    Failed to compile.

```
./src/index.tsx
(60,14): error TS2322: Type '{ component: ComponentClass<{}>; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Rea...'.
  Type '{ component: ComponentClass<{}>; children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteProps>'.
    Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
      Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined> | ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any...'.
        Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined>'.
```

See also the App, Content and one of the page (e.g. Profile) definitions:

```
// App:
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { GlobalState } from '../reducers';
export class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="viewport" className="App" />
    );
  }
}
function select(state: GlobalState) {
  return state.sessionState;
}
export default connect(select)(App);

// Content:
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import Header from '../header/Header';
import Footer from '../footer/Footer';
export default class Content extends 
React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className="Layout" id="container" />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Login:
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
export default class Login extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="email" value="" />
                <input type="password" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Profile:
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
export default class Profile extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, void> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Profile
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to base my implementation on the following GitHub repository
[dictionary-react-redux-typescript](https://github.com/goblindegook/dictionary-react-redux-typescript/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is the same issue as I have asked a question for. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250465/react-router-typescript-type-error). I believe it got fixed so try updating your "@types/react-router" package.